# explorer and mozilla doesn't show website calendar

Tags: html, date, mozilla, explorer

**type="Date"**

explorer and mozilla doesn't show calendar, but in  chrome and opera it works normally. what can be the problem?

```
<form action="asdfsdf.php" method="post">
from:<input name="Date_1" type="Date" size="15" />
to:<input name="Date_2" type="Date" size="15" />
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is not supporting `<input type="date"/>`. [Check here for supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=date)